# Selecting multiple elements together using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a scenarios where I need to select two elements together and then do a Right Click on them and then perform some operation .

is this possible through selenium ?

As for example :

I have a list of 5 users and I want to delete two users which are next to each other.
I will select both of them,right click and select the delete button to delete both in one shot.

Comment: yeah you can do it by using keyboard event in selenium

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
List<WebElement> allOptions = dropDown.findElements(By.xpath("Your xpath which select both element")); 

// See I used here findelements above not findelement

    for ( WebElement we: allOptions) { 
            Actions action = new Actions(driver).contextClick(we);
            action.build().perform(); // code to perform right click
    }
```

Hope it will help you :)